# AMDGPU VA-API fails on firefox due to libLLVM-13.so

Tags: firefox, amdgpu, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x11, the kernel version is 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu. I installed firefox and turned VA-API on, but I notice error outputs like

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva error: dlopen of /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so failed: libLLVM-13.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
```

whenever I tries to play a video.

vainfo seems to have a fine output

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_8
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.8 (libva 2.6.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 22.0.0-devel for AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT (navi10, LLVM 13.0.1, DRM 3.44, 5.13.0-39-generic)
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

I also tried firefox on snap and flatpak, but both returned the exact same error. The only way I found to access VAAPI are the flatpak version of vlc, which use VA-API version 1.12.0. Is that the problem?

```
[00007fd60c0033a0] gl gl: Initialized libplacebo v4.192.1 (API v192)
libva info: VA-API version 1.12.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/intel-vaapi-driver/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/GL/lib/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_12
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
```

[Version information in Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6hpj.png)

Comment: Hello. Did I read correctly in your question you are using 20.04.1? If this is correct it is way behind in updates. An up to date system is 20.04.4

Comment: Thanks for helping. I checked my version in GNOME settings, I can confirm I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. [Version Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6hpj.png) Maybe that 20.04.1 has something to do with uname -a.

Comment: NP good you are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the package libllvm13 from [apt.llvm.org](https://apt.llvm.org/) for ubuntu focal and vaapi in firefox seems to work fine now with MOZ_DISABLE_RDD_SANDBOX=1 env variable.

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: Trying to open /opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_8
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```